# Android Studio : Unresolved class 'DevSettingsActivity'

Tags: android

I keep facing error: **Unresolved class 'DevSettingsActivity'**

[image]

And I also have **'Error: AndroidManifest.xml doesn't exist or has incorrect root tag'**

[image]

This error doesn't disappear..

I did

```
1) Sync Project with Gradle Files
2) Clean Project -> Build Project
3) Invalidate Caches
```

all these..

BUT nothing resolves my error.
Please help me.

Comment: Check your package... My opinion Somewhere it's in  the package com.hygea.chungchunon

Comment: @GobuCSG check what? can you explain detail?

Comment: That activity not in the com.facebook.react package.

Comment: what about AndroidManifest.xml ? it exists in app/src/main

Comment: Are you new to android?

Comment: @GobuCSG yes T_T

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246613/discussion-between-gobu-csg-and-hyejung).